# Flex Builder 3 not debugging

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, actionscript, flexbuilder

Allope,
I've recently bough Flex Builder 3 and I am completely dissatisfied with its reluctance to debug. It manages to debug a few times, but after that, it just doesn't want to "connect to the debugger".
Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy fix for this. You now have to join the rest of us waiting for Adobe to update Flex Builder with a fix they say they have.

You can find the long sad story here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-16153:

Basically, this is an issue that has been around for months. Adobe says it has a fix - however - they've not released that fix yet. Adobe reports it's a threading issue...

For the rest of us (waiting for this) - if you need to move forward you can:

A) Live with the problem (painful)

1) Note that in the [bug text](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-16153) there are several attempts to work around this - sometimes people find ways to soften the issue - but no one reports a full fix

2) Note that people trying the LocalHost fix - *sometimes* report a gain in productivity - but in most cases they do not.

B) Switch SDKs from 3.2 (or 3.3) to 3.1 ---- No one knows why - but it fixes the problem (you can then include the SWFs you need for 3.2 directly

C) Develop on Mac [Not a smart ass answer - honestly - for whatever reason this bug is not on Flex Builder for the Mac]

Join the bug discussion - on Adobe's site - it's still active as people are still waiting for the fix.

Comment: were you aware that there is a 3.3 sdk? maybe this would help. 
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk
personally I have not experienced the problem so can't help.

Comment: Hi Andrew ... sadly - very sadly - 3.3 and 3.2 are both effected... We can only hope for the Adobe fix does the right thing.

I'll edit my above note - I should have noted 3.3 - not just 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required Flash Debug Player.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

If that doesn't help, you might have to re-install Flex Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on windows vista? It may be this issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2009/03/16/page-cannot-be-found-issue-when-previewing-via-expression-blend.aspx

The page is about silverlight, but I ran into the same issue a while back with the flex debugger, and had to add the following to my host file (which windows defender removed):

127.0.0.1       localhost

This is expanded more upon here:

http://circstar.com/FlashLabUnderground/?p=64

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems but every-time it refuses to connect to the debugger i have justed downloaded and reinstalled the flash debugger and it works fine.  It's a pain but until adobe do anything what can we do?

Have you the tried FlashDeveloper ide? you can build flex project with it and it quite frankly alot better than flex builder for code writing (not ui work).

Hope this helps

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the same symptoms, but I came across a similar problem on one of our development machines after installing Flex Builder 3.  When trying to run our app in debug mode, flex builder took a long time to launch the app and eventually timed out, displaying some message about not being able to connect to the debugger.

I found [this solution](http://therush.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/resolved-flex-builder-3-debugger-stopped-working/) which worked a treat.  While Flex Builder is trying to launch the app:

1. Go to the browser page containing your app/swf, right-click on the swf to bring up the flash context menu.
2. Select **Debugger**
3. Select **Other Machine**
4. Enter **127.0.0.1** in the text field
5. Click **Connect** and hopefully it works.

NB: If Flex Builder tried to launch the app in Firefox, the page never appeared.  It was only when it launched in Safari that I was able to access the browser page and the flash context menu.